# How to measure (manually) how much of my GPU memory is used / available

Tags: tensorflow, out-of-memory, gpu

I'm experimenting with Tensorflow by creating different models and testing them. The problem I'm having right now is that I don't have a clear sense of how big my model could be before I face the OOM (out of memory) error. For sure, I can keep adding layers or making them bigger and see when I'm hitting the limit. But it would be nice if I could measure how much memory my models are occupying.

Using `nvidia-smi` command I can see this:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 430.40       Driver Version: 430.40       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 14%   56C    P2    87W / 280W |  10767MiB / 11178MiB |     37%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0     24329      C   python                                     10747MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But the problem I have with the memory usage here is that no matter how small or big my model is, it always shows the same number! As if Tensorflow will take all no matter what.

I'm looking for a formula that gives me the memory needed by providing it the number of model parameters, batch size, and sample size.

Answer (score 1):

You can use next function:

```
def get_max_memory_usage(sess):
    """Might be unprecise. Run after training"""
    if sess is None: sess = tf.get_default_session()
    max_mem = int(sess.run(tf.contrib.memory_stats.MaxBytesInUse()))
    print("Contrib max memory: %f G" % (max_mem / 1024. / 1024. / 1024.))
    return max_mem
```

Or look into [mem_utils](https://github.com/yaroslavvb/memory_util) by Vladislav Bulatov

Comment: Thanks. Does this include the memory taken by training samples as well? Or is it just the memory taken by the model parameters?

Comment: generally, samples are only stored in system mem and you are not running out of that one. they have to be copied to GPU one (or 2) batches at a time

Comment: I can also highly recommend enabling logging of memory usage on OOM. It might be hard to read, but you can get an idea what uses how much memory

Comment: Thanks again, but could you please verify if this includes the memory needed by training data (be it 1or 2 batches)?

Comment: It would include at least 1 minibatch of memory allocation. If you have prefetch enabled in your data pipeline it might take more space. 1 minibatch should be reflected in your OOM breakdown as memory allocated for a placeholder or smth